# AJAX not giving data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm really sorry to post this here, but I've tried many things but nothing is solving my current problem. 
The problem is that I've got an *AJAX part* that has a *deleting_id*, trough AJAX the deleting_id needs to get to a *separate PHP script*. And there it will be deleted with a prepared statement.

But I'm not getting anything back, not trough the *console bug* or *error_reporting*.

This is the AJAX part:

```
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-danger').click(function(){
    var delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var delete_id_url = 'action=deleting&id='+delete_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "/panel/includes/handlers/404.handler.php",
            data: delete_id_url,
            succes: function responseText()
                    {
                      $.parseJSON(responseText);

                        if(responsetext.indexOf(1) > -1)
                        {
                            alert('Er is helaas geen overeenkomst in onze database gekomen.');
                        }
                        else if(responsetext.indexOf(2) > -1)
                        {
                            alert('Het opgegeven ID nummer is helaas geen geldig getal.');
                        }
                        else if(responsetext.IndexOf(100) > -1)
                        {
                            alert('De opgegeven rij is verwijderd.');
                            $(delete_id).hide();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('or nah');
                        }
                    }
        });
});
```

The 404.handler.php part:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'deleting')
    {
        $intDelete = trim($_POST['id']);
        $errors    = array();

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM error WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
            $stmt->execute();
            $intSelect = $stmt->num_rows();
            $stmt->close();

                // Controle part.
                if($intSelect == 0)
                {
                    $errors[] = 1;
                    $bolean   = true;
                }
                if(!ctype_digit($intDelete))
                {
                    $errors[] = 2;
                    $bolean   = true;
                }

                    if($bolean == false)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 100;

                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM error WHERE id = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();
                    }

                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($errors);
                console.log($errors);
    }
```

I'm really sorry if I'm not clear or anything, English isn't my mother tongue so I'm having trouble with it. Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: `isset($_POST['action']) == 'deleting'` doesn't do what you believe it does. As `isset` returns a boolean and `bool == '..'` equals `bool` in PHP

Comment: change ```succes``` to ```success```?

Comment: @jam3 Thank you that helped! There are still some minor bugs but that I can fix by myself.

Comment: @RezaMO also think about using HTTP ```DELETE```, rather than ```POST``` for a RESTful solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'deleting')
```

isset returns a boolean, so this never passes.
You need:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'deleting')
```

EDIT

Also, as noted in comments and the other answer, `console.log` is javascript, not php, so remove that. Lastly, whilst unrelated to your problem why are you posting ajax to a file named `404.handler.php`? The name suggests this file has a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
success: function responseText(response)
                {
                  $.parseJSON(response);

                    if(response.indexOf(1) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('Er is helaas geen overeenkomst in onze database gekomen.');
                    }
                    else if(response.indexOf(2) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('Het opgegeven ID nummer is helaas geen geldig getal.');
                    }
                    else if(response.IndexOf(100) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('De opgegeven rij is verwijderd.');
                        $(delete_id).hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('or nah');
                    }
                }
    });
```

Also remove in your PHP file

change the firs line from

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'deleting')
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'deleting')
```

and remove this line

`console.log($errors);`

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you misspelled the word "succes" in your AJAX `success` function?

You also did not send teh responseText variable to your success function:

```
success: function(responseText){
```

When troubleshooting this sort of problem, I usually insert some feedback tests inside my code.

The first check just ensures that the AJAX code has reached the PHP handler.  If I see **Got to here 01**, then I know I got at least that far.

Next, I check at each point where the code could fail -- inside if statements, after a database lookup, etc. This helps me narrow down exactly which part of the code is failing. I never find the problem immediately and usually have to add a few more tests, and then a few more, and then ***"A ha! A missing semi-colon!"***

For Example:

```
echo 'Got to here 01 / ';
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'deleting'){
echo 'Got to here 02 / ';
    $intDelete = trim($_POST['id']);
    $errors    = array();

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM error WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
        $stmt->execute();
        $intSelect = $stmt->num_rows();
        $stmt->close();
echo 'Got to here 03 / ';

            // Controle part.
            if($intSelect == 0)
            {
echo 'Got to here 04 / ';
                $errors[] = 1;
                $bolean   = true;
            }
            if(!ctype_digit($intDelete))
            {
echo 'Got to here 05 / ';
                $errors[] = 2;
                $bolean   = true;
            }

                if($bolean == false)
                {
echo 'Got to here 06 / ';
                    $errors[] = 100;

                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM error WHERE id = ?");
                        $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                }

echo 'Got to here 07 / ';
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($errors);
            console.log($errors);
}
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/panel/includes/handlers/404.handler.php",
        data: delete_id_url,
        success: function(responseText){
           alert( responseText ); 

           //the rest of your code follows
        }
```

Now, you can see what you are getting back from the server, without guessing.